# Наращения в датах

Tags: наращение

Период 40-х—80-х гг. XX в. был...
В 20-е — 30-е гг. было...
Правильно ли проставлены наращения?
В разных источниках по-разному.

Comment: Непонятно, почему в одном случае вы отделили тире пробелами, а в другом нет.

Comment: Скопировал из оригинального текста. Наверное, пробелы не нужны.

Comment: По-моему с ними всё-таки лучше, по крайней мере при наличии наращений.

Comment: Странный ответ: "По-моему с ними всё-таки лучше", ведь вопрос был: "Правильно ли?".

Comment: Разве я отвечал? Я только комментировал. ;)

Comment: Такие комменты только отвлекают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно будет без повторов: 40—80-х гг. XX в.; в 20—30-е гг.